# Populating data using a Pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table like this,

```
country 2007    2008    2009
 UK      5       10      20
 uk      5       10      20
 us     10       30      40
 us     10       30      40
```

But I want to populate the table like this,

```
country year    Total volumn
 uk     2007    10
 uk     2008    20
 uk     2009    40
 us     2007    20
 us     2008    60
 us     2009    80
```

How do I do this in SQL server 2008 using Pivot table or any other method.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2499a

Comment: could post more details please, but on first inspection read into Pivot() Over()

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT country, [year], SUM([Total volumn]) AS [Total volumn]
FROM (
      SELECT country, [2007], [2008], [2009]
      FROM dbo.test137
      ) p
UNPIVOT 
([Total volumn] FOR [year] IN ([2007], [2008], [2009])
) AS unpvt
GROUP BY country, [year]
ORDER BY country, [year]
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2499a/9)

Comment: very nice. might want to add  ORDER BY country, year  to see the result in the order as in the specified goal.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following - and remember to change [DB] with your own database name. In my example you do not need to write the years, but they are extracted automatically for you.

```
-- will contain the temporary total
create table #tempResult (total int) 

-- get all countries
declare @countries table (country varchar(50))
insert into @countries
select country from table1

-- get all years
declare @years table(id int identity(1,1), [year] int)
insert into @years
SELECT column_name
FROM [DB].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Table1'
and column_name != 'country'

-- get all combinations
declare @result table(id int identity(1,1),country varchar(50),[year] int,total int)
insert into @result 
select distinct upper(c.country),y.[year],0
from @years as y,@countries as c

-- will be used for the looping
declare @counter int
select @counter = 1

while @counter <= (select count(*) from @result)
begin

declare @year int
declare @country varchar(50)

-- get year and country in question
select @year = [year] from @result where id = @counter
select @country = country from @result where id = @counter

declare @total int
select @total = (select sum(@year) from table1 where country = @country)

-- insert temp result 
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'insert into #tempResult select sum([' + cast(@year as varchar(50)) + ']) from table1 where country = ''' + @country + ''''
print @sql

exec (@sql)

-- extract
select top 1 @total =  total from #tempResult

-- update respectively
update @result set total = @total
where country=@country and [year]=@year

-- clear
delete from #tempResult

select @counter = @counter + 1
end 

 -- select result
 select * From @result 

 drop table #tempResult
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008+, then you can use CROSS APPLY to unpivot the data from columns into rows.

You can use the VALUES clause with CROSS APPLY:

```
select distinct t.country,
  c.year,
  c.totalvolumn
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  values 
  ('2007', 2007),
  ('2008', 2008),
  ('2009', 2009)
) c(year, TotalVolumn)
order by t.country, c.year;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95384/5)

Or you can use UNION ALL with CROSS APPLY:

```
select distinct t.country,
  c.year,
  c.totalvolumn
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  select '2007', 2007 union all
  select '2008', 2008 union all
  select '2009', 2009 
) c(year, TotalVolumn)
order by t.country, c.year;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95384/6).

This can also be written using a UNION query:

```
select country, '2007' year, 2007 totalVolumn
from yourtable 
union
select country, '2008' year, 2008 totalVolumn
from yourtable 
union
select country, '2009' year, 2009 totalVolumn
from yourtable 
order by country, year;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95384/8)